# pb 10.5 rtf datawindow insertdocument function crashes in vista m/c

Tags: powerbuilder

Application : Powerbuilder 10.5 Build 4523

RTF insert document function is used to insert rtf data into RichTextEdit Datawindow.

dw_1 RichtextEdit Datawindow
rte_1 Richtext Edit control

```
    dw_1.Object.DataWindow.RichText.DisplayOnly = false
rte_1.SaveDocument(ls_docname, FileTypeRichText!)   

dw_1.accepttext()   
dw_1.selecttextall()
dw_1.clear()
dw_1.insertdocument(ls_docname, false, FileTypeRichText!)

dw_1.ShowHeadFoot(true,false)
dw_1.retrieve(il_patienttestno)
dw_1.ShowHeadFoot(false,false)
dw_1.Object.DataWindow.RichText.DisplayOnly = TRUE
```

Application works fine in Windows XP but crashes only in Windows Vista & Windows 7 PC.Is there any workaround or suggestions to overcome issue?

Answer (score 0):

The release notes for PowerBuilder 10.5.2 noted a problem with the RTE control on Vista:

Support for Microsoft Vista operating system

PowerBuilder 10.5.2 provides runtime support for applications deployed
to the Microsoft Vista operating system. The Vista operating system is
not supported for development.

PowerBuilder 10.5.2 applications are 32-bit applications, but testing
has been performed on both the 32-bit Vista Business Edition and the
64-bit Vista Business Edition. ***Rich text features are currently not
fully supported on the Vista operating system. For more information
about unsupported features, see ÂVista issuesÂ.***

Vista does not ship with the Windows standard help display program
WinHlp32.exe. If your application uses Windows Help (.hlp) files, your
users can download the executable from links on the Microsoft Web
site.

You might need to try a later version.